# Is the SQLAlchemy text function exposed to SQL Injection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm learning how to use SQL Alchemy, and I'm trying to re-implement a previously defined API but now using Python.

The REST API has the following query parameter:

```
myService/v1/data?range=time:2015-08-01:2015-08-02
```

So I want to map something like `field:FROM:TO` to filter a range of results, like a date range, for example.

This is what I'm using at this moment:

```
 rangeStatement = range.split(':')
                if(len(rangeStatement)==3):
                    query = query.filter(text('{} BETWEEN "{}" AND "{}"'.format(*rangeStatement)))
```

So, this will produce the following WHERE condition:

```
WHERE time BETWEEN "2015-08-01" AND "2015-08-02"
```

I know SQL Alchemy is a powerful tool that allows creating queries like `Query.filter_by(MyClass.temp)`, but I need the API request to be as open as possible.

So, I'm worried that someone could pass something like `DROP TABLE` in the `range` parameter and exploit the `text` function

Comment: If you are building queries using string formatting then the damage has already been done.  Use placeholders and `bindparams`.

Comment: It is a learning project, I'm too used to Java and Spring framework for the data access layer and I'm trying to find out how to do the same in Python (without relying on Django and Django Framework), so, I can change the queries.
What I don't want to change is the API Spec

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If queries are constructed using string formatting then `sqlalchemy.text` will not prevent SQL injection - the "injection" will already be present in the query text.  However it's not difficult to build queries dynamically, in this case by using [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to get a reference to the column.  Assuming that you are using the ORM layer with model class `Foo` and table `foos` you can do

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
...
col, lower, upper = 'time:2015-08-01:2015-08-02'.split(':')

# Regardless of style, queries implement a fluent interface,
# so they can be built iteratively

# Classic/1.x style
q1 = session.query(Foo)
q1 = q1.filter(getattr(Foo, col).between(lower, upper))
print(q1)
```

or

```py
# 2.0 style (available in v1.4+)
q2 = sa.select(Foo)
q2 = q2.where(getattr(Foo, col).between(lower, upper))
print(q2)
```

The respective outputs are (parameters will be bound at execution time):

```sql
SELECT foos.id AS foos_id, foos.time AS foos_time 
FROM foos 
WHERE foos.time BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

and

```sql
SELECT foos.id, foos.time 
FROM foos 
WHERE foos.time BETWEEN :time_1 AND :time_2
```

SQLAlchemy will delegate quoting of the values to the connector package being used by the engine, so you're protection against injection will be as good as that provided by the connector package<sup>*</sup>.

---

<sup>*</sup> In general I believe correct quoting should be a good defence against SQL injections, however I'm not sufficiently expert to confidently state that it's 100% effective.  It will be more effective than building queries from strings though.

Comment: Assuming that the `time` column` is a `Date` type, you could convert `lower` and `upper` to `datetime.date` instances before querying.  Then you can be confident both that the column name is correct and the dates don't include any injections.

Comment: Awesome, I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: And some connectors might not even quote values, but send them to the DBMS separately from the query.